# Roblox: how to script VectorForce

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm very new (2 days) to Roblox and Lua, so don't bite me too hard please.. =)

What I am trying to do is to script VectorForce for the Part I've also instanced from code.
In simulation Attachment and VectorForce did create, but without any expected effect.

Please, look at my script and tell me where do I need to dig.

```lua
local sandblock = script.Parent
local sandblock_health = 5

local function blockJump(object)
    local jump_att = Instance.new("Attachment", object)
    local jump_force = Instance.new("VectorForce", object)
    jump_force.ApplyAtCenterOfMass = true
    jump_force.Attachment0 = jump_att
    jump_force.RelativeTo = Enum.ActuatorRelativeTo.World
    jump_force.Force = Vector3.new(10,1000,-10)
    jump_force.Enabled = true
    -- here: what is the difference between Enabled and Active?
    --jump_force.Active = true
end

local function onTouch(object)
    --print("К блоку прикоснулся "..object.Name)
    if object.Name == "Handle" then
        sandblock_health = sandblock_health - 1
        print(sandblock_health)
        
        if sandblock_health < 1 then
            local sandblock_drop1 = Instance.new("Part", workspace)
            sandblock_drop1.Size = Vector3.new(2,2,2)
            sandblock_drop1.Position = sandblock.Position + Vector3.new(0,5,-1)
            blockJump(sandblock_drop1)
            sandblock_drop1.Material = "Metal"
            sandblock_drop1.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Gold")
            sandblock_drop1.Name = "Gold"
            
            print("Вы добыли "..sandblock_drop1.Name)
            sandblock:Destroy()
        end
    end
end

sandblock.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

Comment: what is that "expected effect"?  how does the behaviour of your code differ from your expectations? are there any error messages?

Comment: Piglet, "expected effect" is to be pushed up in the sky with the force of 1000 – just for test. Observed effect is the absence of any force applied to the Part. And no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
The product of workspace's gravity and part's mass is much higher than 1000 in my Force vector.

Code below works as expected:

```lua
jump_force.Force = Vector3.new(10, game.Workspace.Gravity * object.Mass * 1.35, -10)
jump_force.Enabled = true
wait(0.4)
jump_force.Enabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is that when you made the `onTouch` function, you had a parameter: `object`. However when you called the function on a player touching the part, you put no parameter: `sandblock.Touched:Connect(onTouch)`. To fix this, do: `sandblock.Touched:Connect(onTouch(<object_parameter>))`

Comment: The object parameter is provided by the Touched event.  Your solution will result in an attempt to call nil error because the local function onTouch doesn't return anything, and that nil result will be passed to the Touched connection.

Comment: DemoNemo5, as far as I understand the whole idea of that function connection to the event is to have passed to the function any object that touches the Part, not a certain one. Thanks, Kylaaa